# Basic timestamp using php

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to display timestamps but I really have no idea how to do it..
btw an introduction to timestamps would be great, I really have no idea what it is, what it does.kindly explain it in a beginner's level.

The timestamps should be seconds.
The first record is always given a timestamp of 0 because it signifies the start of the drinking session.

Basically, what I want is that there will be a button "+" which will automatically display timestamps...

the timestamp at which the intake is added by the user. the timestamp will be the time when the user tapped on a “+” button to record the intake.

Note: I want it to be done in php only..i'm not asking for a code just point me in the right direction on how to achieve what I want.. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a counter, not a timesptamp

Comment: You can use time() which gives a time stamp literally, then do again and subtract from each "lap" to get the seconds since. Sounds like a fun application by the way. Beer fest app?

Comment: LOL...Actually its a blood alcohol content calculator...time()..okay ill check that out...

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning myself but this looked like a fun little project so I thought I'd give it go. You only have to change the path twice. You can change the layout with css.

```
<?php

$timeNow = time();

//When a button is used, if action is set, than
if(isset($_GET['action'])){

    //When reset button is used redirect to start page
    if($_GET['action'] == 'Reset'){
        header('Location: *path*');  //path to your file, e.g. file.php 
    }

    //get all variables
    $timeDiff = $_GET['timeDiff'];
    $timeStart = $_GET['timeStart'];
    $start = $_GET['start'];

    //Make an array out of this string
    $timeDiffArray = explode(',', $_GET['timeDiff']);

    //iterate through the array
    foreach($timeDiffArray AS $diff){
        echo "Time: " . $diff . "<br>";
    }

    //First beer, do this
    if($start == 'true'){

        //change to false, not first loop anymore
        $start = 'false';

        //set time of Start
        $timeStart = time();

    //2 or more beer, do this   
    }else{

        //Set difference between time first beer and start this beer
        $diff = $timeNow - $timeStart;

        // output last differense
        echo "Time: " . $diff . "<br>";

        //add difference to the timediff string
        $timeDiff .= ',' . $diff;
    }

//Start , if action is not set, than
}else{

    $start = 'true'; //true because its going to be the first loop
    $timeDiff = 0; //first always start with 0
    $timeStart = null;  //declaire $timeStart
    echo 'No time set.';
}

//form 
//path to your file, e.g. file.php 
echo '<form action="*path*"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="start" value="' . $start . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeDiff" value="' . $timeDiff . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeStart" value="' . $timeStart . '">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
    </form>';
?>
```